# How to get object from JS content using regex

Tags: node.js, regex, cheerio

I am using Node.js and cheerio, i want options object from the JS script and the text 'cases-linear'
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0V4B.png

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 Highcharts.chart("cases-linear", {
  chart: {
    type: "line",
  },
  title: {
    text: "Total Cases",
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: "(Linear Scale)",
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ["Mar 12", "Mar 13", "Mar 14", "Mar 15", "Mar 16", "Mar 17", "Mar 18", "Mar 19", "Mar 20", "Mar 21", "Mar 22", "Mar 23", "Mar 24", "Mar 25"],
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: "Total Cases",
    },
  },
 });
</script>
```

Comment: The syntax in your input is currently invalid. You're missing a `}`. Is that just a typo? If so, can you fix it?

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance yeah it was type.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the `<script>`'s text content, then match a `{` up to the `)` right before the end of the `</script>`:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(`<script type="text/javascript">
Highcharts.chart("cases-linear", {
 chart: {
   type: "line",
 },
 title: {
   text: "Total Cases",
 },

 subtitle: {
   text: "(Linear Scale)",
 },

 xAxis: {
   categories: ["Mar 12", "Mar 13", "Mar 14", "Mar 15", "Mar 16", "Mar 17", "Mar 18", "Mar 19", "Mar 20", "Mar 21", "Mar 22", "Mar 23", "Mar 24", "Mar 25"],
 },

 yAxis: {
   title: {
     text: "Total Cases",
   },
 },
});
</script>`);
const scriptContent = $('script')[0].children[0].data;
const [, param1, objText] = scriptContent.match(/"*([^"]+)", ({.*)(?=\);)/s);
console.log(param1);
console.log(objText);
eval('var obj = ' + objText)
console.log(obj);
```

`eval` is a simple option if the input is trustworthy. Otherwise, you can use a a JavaScript parser to extract the data.